# Selecting a date range in SQL without a DATE field

Tags: mysql, date-parsing

I have a MySQL database containing a `year` field and a `week_number` field. These are simply `INT` fields. I'd like to be able to execute a query to select between an inclusive range of dates based on week numbers and years, so for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2002 AND week_number BETWEEN 50 AND 10
```

But obviously this fails because there is no concept of dates and times within the query. I could split this particular example into three separate queries with a little parsing of the input data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year = 2000 AND week_number >= 50
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year = 2001
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year = 2002 AND week_number <= 10
```

But I'd like to know if there is a more efficient of effective way of going about it?

**EDIT**

I think I was maybe not clear about the actual problem. What I would like to be able to do is to query in a way that I can get *all* dates between the starting year/week combination and the end year/week combination. That is, in my query above I expect that the following rows are returned:

```
Year  Week Number
2000  50
2000  51
2000  52
2001   1
2001   2

(...and so on for all weeks in 2001...)

2001  51
2001  52
2002   1
2002   2

(...and so on for weeks 3-8...)

2002   9
2002  10
```

Comment: Between should work with int values. May be its your query logic which is failing.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: thanks for your comment, but I don't think it's an issue with the `BETWEEN` statement. The problem is that using between to select a date range from the two separate fields fails because of spanning the date range. Sorry if that wasn't clear; I'll update the question to try and better explain.

Comment: Just take a look at my solution, cause this is the real one. The others are just workarounds of the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (val1 INT NOT NULL, val2 INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(val1,val2));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2013,48),(2013,49),(2013,50),(2013,51),(2013,52),(2014,1),(2014,2),(2014,3),(2014,5);

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (val1,val2) >= (2013,50) AND (val1,val2) <= (2014,3);
+------+------+
| val1 | val2 |
+------+------+
| 2013 |   50 |
| 2013 |   51 |
| 2013 |   52 |
| 2014 |    1 |
| 2014 |    2 |
| 2014 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add those 3 queries results, meaning select all between 2000 weak 50 and 2002 weak 10 use `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (year = 2000 AND week_number >= 50) OR year = 2001 OR (year = 2002 AND week_number <= 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Volkan. Like I said to @Gooner, this would work so long as the date range was known. Otherwise, I have to construct it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (year = 2000 AND week_number >= 50)
OR (year = 2001)
OR ( year = 2002 AND week_number <= 10)
```

Comment: Sort of, but the range is not known ahead of time, so I would have to programmatically construct the query. That's fine, but I was interested whether it could be done more "intuitively" via SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
CONCAT(year,week_number) BETWEEN CONCAT(YEAR(MY_DATE_START),WEEKOFYEAR(MY_DATE_START))
    AND CONCAT(YEAR(MY_DATE_END),WEEKOFYEAR(MY_DATE_END))
```

Replace **MY_DATE_START** and **MY_DATE_END** with your dates.

**Update**

On a second thought you might need left pad with zeroes all the weeks and cast all the strings to integers, so the query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CAST( CONCAT(year,LPAD(week_number,2,"0")) AS UNSIGNED )
    BETWEEN CAST( CONCAT(YEAR(MY_DATE_START),LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(MY_DATE_START),2,"0")) AS UNSIGNED )
    AND CAST( CONCAT(YEAR(MY_DATE_END),LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(MY_DATE_END),2,"0")) AS UNSIGNED )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work for me; it returned zero rows no matter what numbers I plugged in (even selecting from the same year).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT 
   *
FROM table
WHERE DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(year, 1), INTERVAL week_number WEEK) BETWEEN 
DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(2000, 1), INTERVAL 50 WEEK) AND 
DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(2002, 1), INTERVAL 10 WEEK)
```